# Pandas read_csv - running with usecols option fails to read

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read a big tsv file, using panda package. The tsv was extracted from a zip file, which contains separately the header names. It is not written by me - I got this file from an external source (it's a clickstream data). I run this through jupyter notebook, on an amazon virtual instance.

My code is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(zf.open(item[:-4]), 
   compression = None, 
   sep = '\t',
   parse_dates = True,
   names = df_headers,
   usecols = columns_to_include,
   error_bad_lines = False)
```

df_headers are 680 fields which were provided on a spearate tsv.
My problem is that I get hundreds of errors of the type:

Skipping line 158548: expected 680 fields, saw 865

Skipping line 181906: expected 680 fields, saw 865

Skipping line 306190: expected 680 fields, saw 689
Skipping line 306191: expected 680 fields, saw 686

Skipping line 469427: expected 680 fields, saw 1191

Skipping line 604104: expected 680 fields, saw 865

and then the operation stops, with the following Traceback

raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')

and then:
pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:7988)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:8244)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:9261)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas/parser.c:10190)()

CParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 680 and found 489

This is not the first file I'm reading in this way - I read a lot of files and usually got less than 10 such errors, which I could just ignore and read the files. I don't know why this time the number of problematic rows is so big and why the reading stops.
How can I proceed? I can't even open the tsv because they are huge, and when I tried one of the tools which are supposed to be able to open big files - I could n't find the lines of the errors, as the row numbers were not similar to the ones reported in the errors...(i.e. I couldn't just go to row 158548 and see what is the problem there...)
Any help would be VERY appreciated! This is quite crucial for me.

**Edited:**
When I run the read_csv without the usecols option (I tried it only on a subset of the big file) - it succeeds. For some reason the usecols causes some problem for pandas to identify the real columns... I updated the pandas version to 0.19.2, as I saw that there were some bug fixes regarding the usecols option, but now I have a worse problem - when I run the read on a subset of the file (using nrows=) I get different results with or without usecols: with usecols I get the following error:

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.

and now I even don't know in which line...

If I run it without usecols I manage to read BUT - I manage to do it only for a subset of the data (200000 out of ~700000 lines) - when I try to read 200000 rows each time, and then append the created Data Frames I get a memory problem error.....

The number of usecols columns is around 100, and the number of overall columns is almost 700. I have dozens of such files, where each one has around 700000 lines.

Comment: It probably means some fields on those rows contains commas, so the parser treat them as additional separator markers. you should review if the file format is correct, or if you haven't forgotten arguments on read_csv like quoting parameters

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestion how to review the file? It's too big to open in excel...

Comment: my piggy would be `print(open('sickfile.tsv).readlines()[158548]))`

Comment: Try the generalized, [`pd.read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html), and not `pd.read_csv`.

Comment: Thanks, @Parfait, Boud, none of this worked... I edited the question - there is some problem with the usecols option

Answer (score 1):

Answering to a specific case: when you are load a dataframe in pandas without header (labeled dataframes of pass/fail occurences, etc), the file has a large number of columns and there are some empty columns, so there will occur an issue during the process (Error: too many columns specified...)

For this case/purpose try to use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, low_memory=False)
```

> `low_memory` permit you load all of this data with complete empty columns even in sequence.

**Notes:**

- considering pandas imported as pd
- considering your files in the same directory of your jupyter notebook
- laptop with 16GB RAM memory + i5 vPro 2 cores